# How to make background process echo to the main shell prompt?

Tags: bash, shell, background-process

I have two shell files, `A.sh` and `B.sh`. `B.sh` is called by execution within `A.sh` such as the following:

```
#A.sh
./B.sh &
```

Inside `B.sh`, there is an `echo` for example

```
#B.sh
echo "This is B.sh"
```

I want to make this visible to `A.sh` prompt such that when I run `A.sh`, I will be able to see

```
This is B.sh
```

How do I make this happen?

Comment: What prompt are you talking about? `B.sh` inherits its standard output from `A.sh`, so any output from `B.sh` will go to the same place that output from `A.sh` would go. However, since `A.sh` and `B.sh` are running independently, the order in which output from the two are merged is unpredictable.

Comment: That should happen automatically. Maybe you should be more explicit in the code you are showing. Without info we can not tell why output is being subverted.

Comment: What are you really trying to achieve? (I hope it's not some sort of IPC in bash...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "prompt" you mean merely seeing the output of `B.sh` when running `A.sh`, then it is how it works by default: output of all programs started by `A.sh` will show out in it's  stdout/stderr.

If you really mean the shell prompt (as in `PS1`), then you should do something like:

```
export PS1=$(./B.sh)
```

If you want your prompt to be completely dynamic (i.e. update every time it shows) see `PROMPT_COMMAND` variable (assuming you are using `bash`).